# Meaning of automated test

Tags: java

I am really caught up about what are automated tests for a simple program of reading data from a file and finding the sums,average and min I feel like it has an obvious answer as I am thinking of test cases but I have no clue what it means. Can anyone please shed some light about it ?

Comment: It means that you write some code for some testing framework, which you can run the test with a single click of button.

Comment: Look at JUnit tutorials, or TDD tutorials. That should give you an idea of what automated (unit) tests usually mean to a developer, thought they are not the entirety of what an automated test can be.

Comment: Start with a search first, please (e.g. see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5404/The-benefits-of-automated-unit-testing) - however, unlike the previous comments, I would argue that **manually** running Unit tests is *not* **automated** testing even though Unit tests can be a form of "test *automation*"; this can somewhat depend upon context of "automated".

Comment: Thank you so much guys, went through the JUnit tutorials and some other material, thanks for the help, I really appreciate it. I didn't know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

> I am really caught up about what are automated tests for a simple program of reading data from a file and finding the sums,average and min I feel like it has an obvious answer as I am thinking of test cases but I have no clue what it means.

OK ... take a long breath.

Automated tests are tests that can be run automatically on your code.  By automating the tests, you ensure that:

- it is easy (i.e. not labour intensive) to run the tests whenever you need to,
- *all* of the tests can be run ... not just the ones that you remember to do, and
- testing is repeatable.

(The other kind of testing is where you manually run the program with different inputs, different configurations, different scenarios.)

There are different kinds of automated testing.

- The simplest kind for a Java program is unit testing using JUnit (or a similar unit test framework).  The idea of unit testing is that you write behavioural tests for the individual components of the application (e.g. methods and classes) and assemblies of components.
- Another kind of testing focuses on the system as a whole.  This is called system or integration testing.  Here you pick some task within the capabilities of the complete application, use scripting (or something) to get it to perform that task, and check that the results (e.g. outputs, database updates, etc) are correct.

---

In your case, it sounds like your application might be too simple for unit testing.  But either way, what you would need to do is arrange some Java code (or shell some other kind of scripting) that:

- runs the application with known input files,
- captures the output,
- compares the output with a known "correct" result for the input.

You also need to make sure that your tests check the "edge" cases; e.g. empty input files, input files containing invalid data, and so on.